# Fork function doesn't return 0 value?

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork, pid

When i call fork() in main.I don't get 0 value for child process id.
My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){


    pid_t pid = fork();
    printf("pid in child=%d and parent=%d\n",getpid(),getppid());       
    wait(NULL);

}
```

And the output :

```
pid in child=15690 and parent=11593
pid in child=15691 and parent=15690
```

Where is the problem? As i know i should have got 0 value for child process in the second line.

Comment: It's the pid returned by `fork` that will be zero in the child.  Both child and parent will have pids, but the child presumably doesn't need to know its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually use the value of `pid` in your `printf` statement.

The result of `fork()` is zero for the forked process, but its process id as gained by `getpid()` is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

$ man getpid

> getpid() returns the process ID of the calling process.

$ man fork

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.

What you print is real PID like in ps command